# Why do I get corrupted results if I run GPU dense optical flow algorithm concurrently?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

While using OpenCV CUDA dense optical flow in parallel I noticed that *sometimes* I get corrupted optical flow results, though I run it on different `cuda::GpuMat`s and in separate `cuda::Stream`s with separate `Algorithm` instances.

After some experiments with the code I found out that if I protect `DenseOpticalFlow::calc()` call with `mutex` or run only one thread, I *always* get correct (not corrupted) results.

I reduced my code to minimum reproducible example where I run optical flow algorithm on same input images multiple times in multiple threads:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat frames[2] = { imread("im0.jpg"), imread("im1.jpg") };
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) cvtColor(frames[i], frames[i], COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Size frameSize = frames[0].size();

    vector<thread> workers;
    mutex m;

    for (int id = 0; id < 2; ++id) // 2 threads
        workers.emplace_back([&, id]()
    { // lambda
        // Separate Stream, Algorithm and GpuMats for each thread
        auto algoGpu = cuda::OpticalFlowDual_TVL1::create();
        cuda::Stream stream; 
        cuda::GpuMat optFlow(frameSize, CV_32FC2);
        cuda::GpuMat gpuFrame[2] = {
            cuda::GpuMat(frameSize, CV_8UC1),
            cuda::GpuMat(frameSize, CV_8UC1) 
        };
        Mat downloaded, converted;
        Mat channels[2] = { Mat(), Mat() };

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) gpuFrame[i].upload(frames[i], stream);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { // run 1000 times with SAME input
            {
                //unique_lock<mutex> l(m); // WORKS OK IF UNCOMMENTED !!!!!
                algoGpu->calc(gpuFrame[0], gpuFrame[1], optFlow, stream);
            }

            if (id == 0) { // show results from same single thread
                optFlow.download(downloaded, stream);
                stream.waitForCompletion();

                split(downloaded, channels);
                channels[0].convertTo(converted, CV_8UC1, 100, 128);
                imshow("flow", converted);
                waitKey(1);
            }
        }

        stream.waitForCompletion();
    });

    for (auto& worker : workers) worker.join();
    return 0;
}
```

If I uncomment `//unique_lock<mutex> l(m);` I get same valid result image for every call. But if I leave it commented, approximately half of the results are corrupted.

Input images:

[image: im0]
[image: im1]

Correct result:

[image: correct]

Examples of corrupted result:

[image: corrupt1]
[image: corrupt2]

I use OpenCV 4.0 with CUDA 10.1.

Comment: Apparently there’s a race condition which you avoid by using a lock. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @mkrieger1, no, I'm asking why do I need that lock? Why is there the race condition?

Comment: See the Detailed Description NOTE section on this link.  https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/df3/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1Stream.html  It seems to imply that calling the same API with different data (as you are doing when you call calc(...) can result in problems with GPU memory being updated by other async tasks before a previous task has finished with it.

Comment: @JohnSheridan So what should I do to achieve concurrent optical flow calculation? Is it possible to do at all? May my mutex protected calc() call be a temporary fix for the problem or are there any more proper solutions?

Comment: @JohnSheridan also that note seems to be about enquing same api calls with different data to the same Stream. But I use separate Stream's for separate threads.

Comment: @Oliort apologies for the delay in responding. I've been travelling. You pose great questions that are beyond my ability to answer. I was just observing that your calls to calc() are effectively asynchronous, with the GPU as the common resource. The docs indicate that different operation types don't overlap in terms of their usage of GPU memory, and the seeming implication from that clarification in the docs is that a single call type will at least partially use the same GPU memory. This seems incredibly restrictive, so there is every possibility that I'm totally wrong on this.

Comment: My colleague posted this to OpenCV repo and it was marked as bug: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16013

Comment: Good to have the bug reference. Might help anyone else who hits this issue.

Comment: This is an exemplary question: minimal, to the point, and totally reproducible. Kudos! And your contribution led to a bug being fixed. Thank you for your effort in making OpenCV better for all of us! Signed, a user about a month away from having to run parallel optical flow problems. You saved me some headache!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now resolved by [this PR](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/17556), and will be reflected in next release of OpenCV.